# How to create status logs for shell script in Linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging

I have a shell script. To this script I am passing arguments from a file. This file contains tables names

The script is working fine. I am able execute the command for all the tables in the file.

`shell script`

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0 input file "; exit 1; }
input_file=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log 
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

#Function to get the status of the job creation
function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
                #exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}

while read table ;do 
  sqoop job --exec $table > /home/$USER/logging/"${table}_log" 2>&1
done < ${input_file}

g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS "Sqoop job ${table}"
```

I am trying to collect the `status logs` for the script.

I want to collect the `status logs` for each table individually.

what I want

```
2017-04-28 20:36:41 [ERROR] sqoop job table1 EXECUTION [Status] 2 : failed
2017-04-28 20:36:41 [ERROR] sqoop job table2 EXECUTION [Status] 2 : failed
```

What I am getting

If the script for last table fails

```
2017-04-28 20:38:41 [ERROR] sqoop job EXECUTION [Status] 2 : failed
```

If the script for the last table is successful then

```
2017-04-28 20:40:41 [ERROR] sqoop job [Status] 0 : success
```

What am I doing wrong and what changes should I make to get desired results.

Comment: Move the last two lines in your code to inside the `while` loop. Otherwise, it will only run for the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Munir Do you mean `g_STATUS=$?` and
`log_status $g_STATUS "Sqoop job ${table}"` these two lines

Comment: Yes...those two lines

Comment: @Munir thank you It worked fine I got the desired result

Comment: @Munir One quick question. Say if If want to copy the `/home/$USER/logging/"${table}_log"` to a different location in Linux for each table. How can I achieve that? I have tried `cp /home/$USER/logging/"${table}_log" /home/$USER/debug/date "+%Y-%m-%d"/logs/`. It says cannot find `/home/$USER/logging/"_log"` No such file or directory

Comment: See my answer below. Any command that you want to run on `$table` needs to be run within the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
while read table ;do 
  sqoop job --exec $table > /home/$USER/logging/"${table}_log" 2>&1
done < ${input_file}

g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS "Sqoop job ${table}"
```

to

```
while read table ;do 
  sqoop job --exec $table > /home/$USER/logging/"${table}_log" 2>&1
  g_STATUS=$?
  log_status $g_STATUS "Sqoop job ${table}"
  # Any other command you want to run on using $table should be placed here
done < ${input_file}
```

The `while` loop only runs the code within the `while` and `done` lines. So to log for all tables, you need to run the logging inside the while loop.

Also, `$table` changes in iteration of the loop, so any command that you want to run on all tables, you need to run inside the loop.

Comment: One quick question Say if I want to have one email sent out for each failed job in the above script,or one email for all the failed jobs of the `input_file` what changes do I need to do